# CUPS how to change font for printing text files

Tags: text, fonts, font-size, cups, lpr

On a Linux Mint (17) system I want to print plain (formatted) text files (UTF8) from the command line. Pages are separated with a formfeed (\f or 0x0c).

LPR works fine but I have a large font (12pt?) and it looks as thin courier.
I want to change the font into a smaller fontsize (10pt or 11pt) and another monospace fonttype. The CUPS documentation is not giving me the answer.

I am looking forward  for instructions to change the (default) font and fontsize for printing with CUPS LPR.